# How do i set Savepoints for Linq to SQL and use "NO" ExecuteCommand?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions, savepoints

```
    TransactionScope TransactionABC = new TransactionScope();
    try
    {
        context.Connection.Open();
        {
            context.ExecuteCommand("insert into test (test) values (1)")
            context.SubmitChanges();
                    context.ExecuteCommand("savepoint test");

            context.ExecuteCommand("insert into test (test) values (2)")
            context.SubmitChanges();

                    context.ExecuteCommand("rollback to test");
            }
    TransactionABC.Complete();
    TransactionABC.Dispose();

            }
   catch (Exception ec)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(" ", ec.Message);
    }
   finally
    {
        context.Connection.Close();
    }
```

It works, but only with ExecuteCommand. I want to use a function, because i can't see what happens in the savepoint !

Comment: You **really** want to be `using` the transaction-scope. Otherwise when you get an exception you've left the transaction open - which is bad. It should be `using(var tran = new TransactionScope()) { /* code */ tran.Complete(); }` - then it is correctly disposed upon exit for both success and failure, with only success calling `Complete()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise simply not to. It isn't necessarily what you want to hear, but *especially* when mixing with `TransactionScope`, save-points aren't a great idea. `TransactionScope`s can be nested, but the first rollback dooms *everything*, and the commit only happens at the outermost transaction.

In most scenarios I can think of, it is better to sanitise the data *first*. You can (and should) also use contraints for a safety net, but if you *hit* that safety net, assume big problems and rollback everything.

---

Example of nested transactions:

```
public void DebitCreditAccount(int accountId, decimal amount, string reference)
{
  using(var tran = new TransactionScope())
  {
    // confirm account exists, and update estimated balance
    var acc = db.Accounts.Single(a => a.Id == accountId);
    acc.BalanceEstimate += amount;
    // add a transaction (this defines the **real** balance)
    db.AccountTransactions.InsertOnSubmit(
         new AccountTransaction {
                 AccountId = accountId, Amount = amount,
                 Code = amount >= 0 ? "C" : "D",
                 Reference = reference });
    db.SubmitChanges();
    tran.Complete();
  }
}
public void Transfer(int fromAccountId, int toAccountId,
           decimal amount, string reference)
{
  using(var tran = new TransactionScope())
  {
    DebitCreditAccount(fromAccountId, -amount, reference);
    DebitCreditAccount(toAccountId, amount, reference);
    tran.Complete();
  }
}
```

In the above, `DebitCreditAccount` is atomic - we'll either add the account-transaction **and** update the estimated balance, or neither. If this is the *only* transaction, then it is committed at the end of this method.

However, in the `Transfer` method, we create another outer transaction; we'll either perform **both** `DebitCreditAccount`, or **neither**. Here, the inner `tran.Complete()` (in `DebitCreditAccount`) **doesn't** commit the db-transaction, as there is an outer transaction. It simply says "I'm happy". Conversely, though, if *either* of the inner transactions is aborted (`Dispose()` called without `Complete()`), then the **outer** transaction is rolled back *immediately*, and that transaction will refuse any additional work. The *outer* transaction is committed only if no *inner* transaction was aborted, **and** `Complete()` is called on the outer transaction.

Comment: Thanks mark for answering !
Could you give me a sample of a nested transaction  ?
Thanks,
Nik

Comment: @Mark  
Thanks for the code. 
If the both inner transactions don't work, i got an exception.
Is this nested transaction nearly the same like a savepoint ? I would say no !
I'm looking for a code that is the same like a Savepoint but without ExecuteCommand !

Thanks,
Nik

Comment: @nik - not quite: you can't complete an outer-transaction after you roll-back an inner-transaction. With a save-point you *can* do that.

Answer (score 0):

How about ExecuteQuery?

With DataContext.ExecuteQuery, you send text into the database, just like ExecuteCommand - but you can get query results back from that text.

```
IEnumerable<int> results = ExecuteQuery<int>(@"
DECLARE @Table TABLE(Id int)
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT {0}
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT {1}
SELECT Id FROM Table", 101, -101);


IEnumerable<Customer> results = ExecuteQuery<Customer>( @"
Rollback transaction
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE ID = {0}", myId);
```

Comment: Hallo David,
can you give me an idea, what you meen with ExecuteQuery ?
Tanks,
Nik

Comment: Hello David,
thanks for example, but it is "only" a rollback ! I need a rollback to savepoint ! Or do i understand something miss ?

Regards,
Nik

Comment: you put whatever sql you want in there, just like ExecuteCommand.